# Laravel fetch data from two tables without join with pagination

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, union-all, laravel-pagination

I want to fetch results from two tables **properties** and **properties_x** where `properties.address` or `properties_x.address_x` like `test` with laravel pagination.

There is no foreign key relationship between these two tables.

```
properties

id  name    address
1   test1   
2   test2   
3   test3   
4   test3   test
5   test4   test

properties_x

id  name    address
1   test1_x test
2   test2_x 
3   test3_x 
4   test3_x test
5   test4_x 

    Expected results:
    name     address
    test3    test
    test4    test
    test1_x  test
    test3_x  test
```

Comment: Code formatted and sentence improvements

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `union all` to union two table's datas,

And get the columns from these datas in DB, so you can use pagination.

try it like this:

```php
$p1 = DB::table('properties')
        ->where('address', 'test')
        ->select('name', 'address');

$p2 = DB::table('properties_x')
         ->where('address', 'test')
         ->select('name', 'address');

$p = $p1->unionAll($p2);

DB::table(DB::raw("({$p->toSql()}) AS p"))
->mergeBindings($p)
->select('name', 'address')
->paginate(10);
```

Comment: @HarpalSingh yes, you can, but you need to select the columns as same name, same order and  same count.

Comment: Can, you please provide me the syntax for the same?

Comment: like `$p3 = DB::table('properties_x3')
         ->select('title AS name', 'address'); $p = $p1->unionAll($p2)->unionAll($p3); `

Comment: @HarpalSingh glad it helps

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is another way, but it works for me well

```
$res= [];

$tableONe = Property::where('address','test')->get();

array_push($res,$tableOne);


$tableTwo = PropertyX::where('address','test')->get();

array_push($res,$tableTwo);
```

now $res have both data table together

Comment: But I need data with pagination

Answer (score 0):

union all then laravel query builder provide unionAll method for mysql union. when you are doing big project or ERP level project then mostly you require to use union for getting data from database with multiple table. In Following example you can see how to use union all in Laravel 5.

Example:

```
$silver = DB::table("product_silver")
    ->select("product_silver.name"
      ,"product_silver.price"
      ,"product_silver.quantity");
$gold = DB::table("product_gold")
    ->select("product_gold.name"
      ,"product_gold.price"
      ,"product_gold.quantity")
    ->unionAll($silver)
    ->get();
print_r($gold);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$users = User::select('id','name')
        ->where('name','LIKE','%'.$key.'%'); 
$properties = Property::select('id','name')
             ->where('name','LIKE','%'.$key.'%'); 
$results = Program::select('id','name')
          ->where('name','LIKE','%'.$key.'%') ->union($users)
          ->union($properties)
          ->simplePaginate();
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).