# Fetch data from two tables without join laravel

Tags: mysql, eloquent, laravel-7

Want to fetch data from two different queries since employee table is too large and emp dept would be always one . I am trying to avoid join with dept table instead trying to use below query

**Want to convert below query to Eloquent query**

```
SELECT ename, 
       (SELECT dname FROM dept WHERE dept.deptno=emp.deptno) dname 
FROM EMP
```

[Laravel fetch data from two tables without join with pagination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59735044/laravel-fetch-data-from-two-tables-without-join-with-pagination)

Comment: Why do you think this is better than a JOIN?

Comment: @Barmar had read regarding it long back. Sorry i am unable to find it right now. Could you please correct me if i am wrong

Comment: As long as you have indexes on the `deptno` columns, the join should be fine.

Comment: May i know what is this technique called.

Comment: What you wrote is called "correlated subqery"

Comment: Could you please provide eloquent query for this one

Comment: I don't know Eloquent, but I found this with google: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/doing-a-correlated-query-in-a-subquery

Comment: It's using raw which i am trying to avoid

Answer (score 0):

You could sue this code

```
SELECT ename, dname 
FROM EMP, dept
WHERE dept.deptno=emp.deptno
```

Y hope help you

Comment: I want it in laravel format without join